# Inserting a row into sqlite3 database from python

Tags: python, sqlite

I'm new to using sqlite3 with python.  I'm having trouble with making the insert_row function in my database class.   From the manual on the execute function it appears that I'm doing everything correctly https://docs.python.org/2/library/sqlite3.html.  This function does return a number which appears to be correct for lastrowid. However, when I access sqlite3 via command line the table is empty.

```
def insert_row(self, table, input_dict):
    '''
        (str, dict) -> int
        Add a row to a table in the database
    '''

    count = 0
    col_names = input_dict.keys()
    insert_sql = 'INSERT INTO ' + self.sanitize(table) + ' (' + utils.list_to_char_seperated(col_names, ', ', False) + ') VALUES (' 

    for col in col_names:
        count += 1
        insert_sql += "'" + self.sanitize(input_dict[col]) + "'"

        if count < len(col_names):
            insert_sql += ', '
        else:
            insert_sql += ');'

    cur = self.conn.cursor()

    cur.execute(insert_sql)

    return cur.lastrowid
```

Accessing via command line.

```
    $ sqlite3
    SQLite version 3.11.0 2016-02-15 17:29:24
    Enter ".help" for usage hints.
    Connected to a transient in-memory database.
    Use ".open FILENAME" to reopen on a persistent database.
    sqlite> .open blood_cultures.db 
    sqlite> .tables
    vein_draws
    sqlite> SELECT * FROM vein_draws;
    sqlite>
```

Also if I take the result of the insert_sql variable and insert it directly into the database via a command line connection this works.  So I do not believe it is my insert statement.

Any ideas on what I am doing wrong here?

Comment: what about commit ? `self.conn.commit()`

Comment: Thank you that works. How do I accept your answer?

Comment: For the love of god, don't build your SQL like this. Use parametrized SQL or you'll suffer from SQL injection attacks

Comment: @Samantha that was only a comment, you cannot accept it, but thank you

Comment: @IrmendeJong i agree, i wanted to answer about this, but i admit i can't find a pretty way to provide X parameters in SQL depending on the number of fields in the table. Does it make any sense to build a pattern like this ?

Comment: @PRMoureu you can dynamically construct a parametrized sql query (containing placeholders such as '?') and then pass the list of parameters afterwards.  The key is to NOT put the parameters themselves directly in the constructed sql

Comment: This function could be easily changed to be parametrized however, this project has absolutely no risk of SQL injection.  1. it is not on the web. 2. This database is used temporarily to do data analysis on a large tsv file.  3. the user of the program has full access to the tsv file.  4. Then the database is immediately deleted after the information is extracted.